# How to get c# local sql row from database and modify it

Tags: c#, sql, database, row

I'm new to c# database programming and I am having difficulty retrieving a row of data from my local data base file. I have successfully queried the database for a username but it only returns a count of the lines containing the username. what I need is the whole row of data and then to be able to change one entry and re save the row.

My code looks like this:

```
       int count = 0;

        try
        {
           count = this.usersDBTableAdapter.SearchUserName(this.usersDBDataSet.UsersDB, name);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

my query in the query designer for SearchUserName looks like this:

[image]

It looks like I'm finding the row with the username correctly but I'm stumped as to how to read the data from the row, modify specific entries then write the row back to the database.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava, Umm, did you actually read the question properly? He is using typed dataset and the function in defined in the entity

Comment: Ohh!! @Rahul Thanks. I havent read it properly.